# Plain Sight targetting enemies

Tags: plain-sight

I've only played Plain Sight a little, but have a lot of trouble actually targetting other robots. Any good strategies for overcoming this problem...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Plain Sight [Complete Beginner's Guide](http://beatnikgames.co.uk/index.php/forums/viewthread/7020/):

> **Targeting**
>
> Another basic mechanic that will take some getting used to is the targeting system. The tutorial shows you how to lock onto enemies, but here are some additional points to know:
>
> -When your targeting indicator turns red, it indicates that your “shot” is lined up. However, this doesn’t always guarantee a hit. Sometimes the indicator becomes red when there is part of an object in the way, which you will glace off of and end up missing. Be aware of that little red line and ensure it doesn’t pass through or too close to any surfaces before you try attacking.
>
> -On a similar note, the red targeting indicator tells you that given both players’ current speeds and trajectories, your dash will hit them. If the target suddenly dashes, changes direction, or otherwise messes with their speed/trajectory too much, you will still miss. Make sure to watch for moments when your opponent will be unable to maneuver and release your dash at that point.
>
> -A red targeting indicator is not always required to hit. If you’re close to your target and the indicator isn’t red yet, you might still be able to hit them. Also, once you begin dashing for an attack, the enemy might move INTO a position to get hit. Keep your eyes open for these moments, and with time and experience, you’ll start to learn when dashing early is appropriate.

Hope this helps! That guide is incredibly useful for new players of Plain Sight; I would recommend giving it a good read-through.